# How to access the variable value in a loop in Linux?

Tags: bash, loops

I'm trying to get the variable values in a shell script using a loop as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

VR1a=1.5
VR2a=8.3
VR3a=15

VR1b=0.9
VR2b=5.7
VR3b=20

for j in a b
do
 VR1="VR1$j"
 VR2="VR2$j"
 VR3="VR3$j"
 echo ${!VR1}
 echo ${!VR2}
 echo ${!VR3}

done
```

I would expect the output:

```
For variable a VR1=1.5, VR2=8.3 and VR3=15
For variable b VR1=0.9, VR2=5.7 and VR3=20
```

But the result was:

```
For variable a VR1=VR1a, VR2=VR2a and VR3=VR3a
For variable b VR1=VR1b, VR2=VR2b and VR3=VR3b
```

How can I get the number instead of the variable name?

Comment: Remove all `A`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either use nameref variables:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

VR1a=1.5
VR2a=8.3
VR3a=15

VR1b=0.9
VR2b=5.7
VR3b=20

for j in a b
do
 typeset -n VR1="VR1$j"
 typeset -n VR2="VR2$j"
 typeset -n VR3="VR3$j"
 echo ${VR1}
 echo ${VR2}
 echo ${VR3}
done
```

Or use an associative array:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

typeset -A VR
VR["1a"]=1.5
VR["2a"]=8.3
VR["3a"]=15
VR["1b"]=0.9
VR["2b"]=5.7
VR["3b"]=20

for j in a b
do
 echo "${VR["1$j"]}"
 echo "${VR["2$j"]}"
 echo "${VR["3$j"]}"
done
```